# Compare column values in Dataframes and return difference column name with value in Spark java 8

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, java-8

I have two data frames with 230 columns each and would like to compare the two data frames on one key column  and get column names with values from both of them if any difference in column value in Java 8 with Spark.

```
id  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5
1    A     B      C     D     E
2    X     Y      Z     P     Q

id  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5
1    A     B6     C     D     E
2    X     Y      Z8    P     Q3
```

OutPut

```
id  Col_1 Col_2   Col_3 Col_4 Col_5
1   null  [B,B6]  null  null   null
2   null  null   [Z,Z8] null   [Q,Q3]
```

Using Spark and Java8

```
Df1.except(DF2);

StructType one = DF1.schema();

JavaPairRDD<String, Row> pair1 = DF1.toJavaRDD()
        .mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, String, Row>() {
            public Tuple2<String, Row> call(Row row) {
                return new Tuple2<String, Row>(row.getString(0), row);
            }
        });

JavaPairRDD<String, Row> pair2 = DF2.toJavaRDD()
        .mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, String, Row>() {
            public Tuple2<String, Row> call(Row row) {
                return new Tuple2<String, Row>(row.getString(0), row);
            }
        });

JavaPairRDD<String, Row> subs = pair1.subtractByKey(pair2);
JavaRDD<Row> rdd = subs.values();
Dataset<Row> diff = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, one);
diff.show();
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Comment: Thanks Somehwar. Its working

Comment: can you please accept + upvote?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below solution 
I have tried to solve the problem by keeping Dataframes as Dataframes and you can find inline comments for the code explanation.
The actual solution starts after the line  **//Below is the solution**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;


public class CompareDfs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = Constant.getSparkSess();


        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add("1,A,B,C,D,E");
        list1.add("2,X,Y,Z,P,Q");

        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add("1,A,B6,C,D,E");
        list2.add("2,X,Y,Z8,P,Q3");

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataset(list1, Encoders.STRING()).toDF().selectExpr("split(value, ',')[0] as id",
                "split(value, ',')[1] as Col_1",
                "split(value, ',')[2] as Col_2",
                "split(value, ',')[3] as Col_3",
                "split(value, ',')[4] as Col_4",
                "split(value, ',')[5] as Col_5");
//        df.printSchema();
//        df.show();
        // Convert
        Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.createDataset(list2, Encoders.STRING()).toDF().selectExpr("split(value, ',')[0] as id",
                "split(value, ',')[1] as Col_1",
                "split(value, ',')[2] as Col_2",
                "split(value, ',')[3] as Col_3",
                "split(value, ',')[4] as Col_4",
                "split(value, ',')[5] as Col_5");
//        df1.printSchema();
//        df1.show();

        //Below is the solution
        List<String> columns = Arrays.asList("Col_1", "Col_2", "Col_3", "Col_4", "Col_5"); // List of columns to merge

        // inner join the 2 dataframes
        Dataset<Row> joinedDf = df.join(df1).where(df.col("id").equalTo(df1.col("id")));


        // Iterate throgh the columns
        for (String column : columns) {
            joinedDf = joinedDf
                    .withColumn(column + "_temp",
                            when(df.col(column).equalTo(df1.col(column)), null) // When and otherwise clause for column to array/nul transformation
                                    .otherwise(split(concat_ws(",", df.col(column), df1.col(column)), ",")))
                    .drop(df.col(column)) // Drop column from 1st dataframe
                    .drop(df1.col(column)) // Drop column from 2nd dataframe
                    .withColumnRenamed(column + "_temp", column); // Rename column to the result column name
        }

//                .withColumn("Col_2_t",when(df.col("Col_2").equalTo(df1.col("Col_2")), null ).otherwise(split(concat_ws(",",df.col("Col_2"),df1.col("Col_2")),",")))
        joinedDf.show();


    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to here please consider upvoting + accepting the answer @Tamil

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this using dataframe approach-

```java
  List<Column> cols = Arrays.stream(df1.columns())
                .map(c -> {
                    if (c.equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
                        return col("a.id");
                    else
                        return array(toScalaSeq(Arrays.asList(col("a."+c), col("b."+c))).toBuffer()).as(c);
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Dataset<Row> processedDf = df1.as("a").join(df2.as("b"), df1.col("id").equalTo(df2.col("id")))
                .select(toScalaSeq(cols).toBuffer());


        List<Column> cols1 =  Arrays.stream(df1.columns())
                .map(f -> {
                    if (f.equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
                        return expr(f);
                    else
                        return expr("if(size(array_distinct(" + f + "))==1, NULL, " + f + " ) as " + f);
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        processedDf.select(toScalaSeq(cols1).toBuffer())
                .show(false);
        /**
         * +---+-----+-------+-------+-----+-------+
         * |id |Col_1|Col_2  |Col_3  |Col_4|Col_5  |
         * +---+-----+-------+-------+-----+-------+
         * |1  |null |[B, B6]|null   |null |null   |
         * |2  |null |null   |[Z, Z8]|null |[Q, Q3]|
         * +---+-----+-------+-------+-----+-------+
         */
```

Please refer full code here- [gist](https://gist.github.com/skale1990/26448400c7655543f9e1177dd17763bf#file-javaproblemsolvertest-java-L67)